# How can I find child components by type

Tags: typescript, angular

I want know call the method of child(A) from parent(B).
Using the Output is emit to parent(B) from child(A). and very well working.
But I don't want using this way. I want know how can i find child(A) from parent(B).

A.component.ts

```
@Import {Component, EventEmitter} from '@angular/core';
@Component({
    selector: 'com-a',
    template: '<button (click)="sendDatas()">comA btn</button>',
    outputs: ['getItems']
})
export class ComAClass{
    public getItem = new EventEmitter<any>();
    datas: any[] = ['abc', 'def'];
    constructor(){
        console.log('Hello, I'm Component A');
    }
    sendDatas(){
        this.getItem.emit(this.datas);
    }
    someMethod(){
        console.log('call method of component A');
    }
}
```

and B.component.ts

```
@Import {Component, ...} from '...';
@Import {ComAClass} from '~~/A.component.ts';
@Component({
    selector: 'com=b'
    template: '<com-a name="comA1" (getItem)="getComAItem1($event)"></com-a>
        <com-a name="comA2" (getItem)="getComAItem2($event)"></com-a>
        <button (click)="callSomeMethod()">comB btn</button>'
})
export class ComBClass{
    constructor(){
        console.log('Hello, I'm Component B');
    }
    private getComAItem1(event){
        console.log('comA1 output event');
    }
    private getComAItem2(event){
        console.log('comA2 output event');
    }
    callSomeMethod(){
        // how call the comA1.someMethod()?
    }
}
```

My source is running and printing like this on console.

```
Hello, I'm Component B
Hello, I'm Component A
Hello, I'm Component A
```

I Think B have CompA1, CompA2. B can call the someMethod() of CompA1. and CompA2 too. I want develop like that. But I don't know how call the CompA1, CompA2. My Think is wrong? If my think wrong. What can I do?? only way using the outputs?

please help starter!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `@ViewChildren(ComAClass)` to get all `ComAClass` instances in `ComBClass`'s view.

```ts
export class ComBClass{
    @ViewChildren(ComAClass) comA:QueryList<ComAClass>;

    constructor() {
      // this.comA is not yet initialized when the constructor is executed
    }

    ngOnInit() {
      this.comA.toArray()[0].sendDatas();
    }

    callSomeMethod(){
      this.comA.toArray()[0].someMethod();
    }
}
```

You can also use template variables to address one specific instance

```ts
@Component({
    selector: 'com=b'
    template: '<com-a #coma1 name="comA1" (getItem)="getComAItem1($event)"></com-a>
        <com-a #coma2 name="comA2" (getItem)="getComAItem2($event)"></com-a>
        <button (click)="callSomeMethod()">comB btn</button>'
})
export class ComBClass{
    @ViewChild('coma1') comA1:ComAClass;
    @ViewChild('coma2') comA2:ComAClass;

    constructor(){
        // this.comA1 and this.comA2 is not yet initialized when the constructor is 
        console.log('Hello, I'm Component B');
    }
    private getComAItem1(event){
        console.log('comA1 output event');
    }
    private getComAItem2(event){
        console.log('comA2 output event');
    }
    callSomeMethod(){
        this.comA1.someMethod();
        this.comA2.someMethod();
    }
}
```

Yet another way is to pass the reference also using a template variable

```ts
@Component({
    selector: 'com=b'
    template: '<com-a #coma1 name="comA1" (getItem)="getComAItem1($event)"></com-a>
        <com-a #coma2 name="comA2" (getItem)="getComAItem2($event)"></com-a>
        <button (click)="callSomeMethod(coma1)">comB btn</button>'
})
export class ComBClass{
    constructor(){
        // this.comA1 and this.comA2 is not yet initialized when the constructor is 
        console.log('Hello, I'm Component B');
    }
    private getComAItem1(event){
        console.log('comA1 output event');
    }
    private getComAItem2(event){
        console.log('comA2 output event');
    }
    callSomeMethod(comA1:ComAClass){
        comA1.someMethod();
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow!!!!!! REALLY Thank you!!! @ViewChild is Really working!! Thank you So much!!! by the way! your another way is not working.... that's looks simple than using ViewChild..

Comment: Which way is not working? The last one? Did you get some error?

Comment: callSomeMethod(comA1:ComAClass){
        this.comA1.someMethod();
    }
I'll guess this.comA1 is not found. my webstorm was showing red text and printing unresolved variable on tooltip. and error can't find someMethod() on web console. but using without this. it is working! really thank you !!!! I don't forget your answer!

Comment: Sorry, copy-paste error. In this case `this.` is wrong because we refer to the parameter `comA1`.

Comment: In webstorm console was Property 'comA1' does not exist on type 'ComBClass'. and Cannot read property 'someMethod' of undefined. at web console.

Comment: I assume that error message was while the the redundant `this.` was still there?